# How to stop meteor from injecting data to the head tag?

Tags: meteor

I am new to Meteor, ( have completed few projects in react redux without meteor already).

So the project i am working has a section in the head `<script type="text/inject-data">`

This is giving me a headache during development, as i have no clue why is the data being injected and it takes lot of time to reload during development.

The package that is used for inject data is **staringatlights_inject-data.js**.

To run the project i just use `meteor run --port XXXX`.

Any suggestion on where to look for to stop injecting data to html or other work around is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be a package, called [staringatlights:inject-data](https://atmospherejs.com/staringatlights/inject-data). Did you create a new project via `meteor create <projectname>` or is it a fork/clone/continuation of someone's work?

Comment: If your issue is the package that injects data, why not just `meteor remove packageName`?

Comment: @Jankapunkt its a continuation of someone else's work